# Create Individual SparkSessions for Each Endpoint in a REST Service

Tags: java, apache-spark, spring-boot, session

I am working on a Java REST API which hits multiple endpoints at the same time and all those services runs in parallel. I want my application to use a separate SparkSession for each end point.

Problem Statement:

Whenever I stop a sparkSession using `SparkSession.close()` or `SparkSession.stop()`, it closes the sparkContext itself because of which other services running in parallel fails and sparkContext fails to restart whenever I hit the service again.

I tried following approaches to resolve the problem:

1. Use SparkSession singleton object and create separate SparkSession for each service using `SparkSession.cloneSession()` or `SparkSession.newSession()` and call `SparkSession.close()` or `SparkSession.stop()` to stop the session.

Problem: Stops the SparkContext. Can't call the services repeatedly or in parallel.

2. Create individual SparkContext objects and call a java method to create SparkSession (instead of using a singleton) for each service like this:

   ```
   SparkContext sparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkCassandraConfig.sparkConf());

   SparkSession cloneSparkSession = sparkCassandraConfig.sparkSession(sparkContext).newSession();
   ```

Where `sparkCassandraConfig` is a singleton and it uses `sparkConf()` method to fetch the required spark configurations and uses `sparkSession(SparkContext)` method to built a SparkSession.

and then closing the session using:

```
cloneSparkSession.close();
```

Problem: This approach works if I call the services sequentially but fails when services runs in parallel.

Can anyone suggest a solution for the current approaches or if there is any other approach to create separate SparkSession for each endpoints.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create SparkSession as static block and try to get the SparkSession using `val spark = SprakSession.getorcreate()` method dont stop the session in every method.